# Xcode - How to create a sticky panel window that moves with the main win?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, panel

I have a main appl. window with a toolbar. When user clicks on button X I want to open a small input window that is floating, and is "attached" to the bottom of the main window's toolbar (it should move with the main window until user closes the panel). So, if I use a panel, how do I make it "stick" to the bottom of the main toolbar?

**Edited:**

Ok, since  I am creating windows in IB, I have a class set up that  is supposed to turn a panel into a child. It doesn't work, however. I get an error in the .m class: *Expected identifier or '('*
Why?

```
@interface myClass : NSObject {
    IBOutlet NSWindow *myWin;
    IBOutlet NSPanel *myPan;
}

@end


@implementation myClass

[myWin addChildWindow:myPan ordered:NSWindowAbove];

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the panel a child window of the main window by calling:

```
[mainWindow addChildWindow:yourPanel ordered:NSWindowAbove];
```

This will make the child window follow the main window when the main window is moved.

Answer (score -1):

You shall use the layout positionning in the inspector. Just make sure that sub-view is at fixed distance from bottom and others are elastic.

Comment: You can't do that. Window positions cannot be set relative to another window in Interface Builder and they certainly cannot be set so that they move when another window moves.

Comment: No luck with that in IB, I suppose I'll have to do it programatically :-/

Comment: You'r right. Sorry I was too focussed on iOS context. Missed this was a Mac target. 

You may (never tried) be able to do this if you can use bindings to tie right position to the left x position of the other window.

Have you tried the child window solution proposed above?

Comment: I tried, but can't get it to work! (I posted the code at the top).